# Struggling to prove $T \models_t \alpha \Rightarrow T \vdash \alpha$, $T$ being a theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

$T \models_t \alpha$ is an abbreviation of $\forall\mathcal{A}(\forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models T) \Rightarrow \forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models \alpha))$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a structure and $w$ is a variable assignment. $T \models \alpha$ is an abbreviation of $\forall \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{M} \models T \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \alpha)$.

In my logic book (p. 102 of Wolfgang Rautenberg's *A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (Third Edition), if anyone wants to look up the precise wording), the author states that $T \models_t \alpha$ is equivalent to $T \vdash \alpha$. I've managed to prove $T \vdash\alpha \Rightarrow T \models_t \alpha$, but I struggle with the converse. Here is the proof.

\begin{align*}
T \vdash \alpha &\Leftrightarrow T \models \alpha  &\text{(soundness and completeness of FOL)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{M} \models T \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \alpha) &\text{(definition)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall \mathcal{A}\forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models T \Rightarrow (\mathcal{A}, w) \models \alpha) &\text{(definition)} \\
&\Rightarrow \forall\mathcal{A}(\forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models T) \Rightarrow \forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models \alpha)) &\text{(generally valid implication)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow T \models_t \alpha. &\text{(definition)}
\end{align*}

As we can see, the crucial part is the fourth line. I know that, generally, the converse implication is not always true. However, if the author's claim is true, it must be the case when structures and variable assignments are considered, i.e., $T \models_t \alpha \Rightarrow T \models \alpha$ must also hold. But I have no idea how to prove it and I even fear I could find a counterexample, in which case I'd be hopelessly confused! Any help is dearly appreciated. :)

P.S. Note that the author uses the notation $T \models \alpha$ for $T \models_t \alpha$, expecting that the reader will always presuppose the correct definition due to the consequence relation obtaining between a *theory* and a formula. I expanded the notation to avoid such ambiguity and confusion with the ordinary $\models$.

Comment: Sorry... Page 102: I cannot find the symbol $T \vDash_t \alpha$. Is it your defintion?

Comment: According to the author, a *theory* $T$ is a set of sentences. If so, the variable assignment $w$ is irrelevant, because a sentence either is true in a structure $A$ or it is not.

Comment: If you remove that condition, it does not hold. Consider the usual structure $\mathbb N$ and let $T := (x=0)$ and $\alpha := \forall x (x=0)$. We have that $\alpha$ is false in $\mathbb N$ and obviously $\forall w \vDash T$ is false in $\mathbb N$. Thus (False to False is True) we have that line 4 holds in $\mathbb N$, while line 3 does not.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, this is my definition, taken from the author's definition on p. 82. I added it to avoid confusion with the ordinary satisfiability relation obtaining between any set of formulas and a formula.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I would like to dearly thank you for the crucial insight that $T$ is a set of sentences. I've now (I think) managed to prove the converse and posted the proof as an answer. Any remarks about my proof would be welcome, and I would like to offer you to post your answer so I could upvote and tick it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The generally valid implication is $[\forall b (P(b) \implies Q(b))] \implies [\forall b P(b) \implies \forall b Q(b)]$.

Here, $P(b)$ is $(A, b) \models T$ and $Q(b)$ is $(A, b) \models \alpha$.

To show the above implication, suppose that $\forall b (P(b) \implies Q(b))$. And further suppose $\forall b P(b)$. Consider an arbitrary $b$. Then $P(b)$. And $P(b) \implies Q(b)$. So $Q(b)$.

Edit: the converse does *not* hold. For consider the statement $T :\equiv (a \neq b)$ and $\alpha :\equiv a = b$. Then clearly, it is not the case that $T \models \alpha$. But it is the case that $T \models_t \alpha$.

For suppose given some $A$. And suppose that for all $w$, $(A, w) \models T$. This is equivalent to saying $\forall x \in A \forall y \in A (x \neq y)$, which is in turn equivalent to saying $A$ is empty. If $A$ is empty, then $\forall w ((A, w) \models \alpha)$ holds trivially, since there is no variable assignment $w$ for the variables $a$ and $b$.

Edit: in fact, as suggested, this does hold when one restricts $T$ to have no free variables. This is because if $T$ has no free variables then $(A, w) \models T$ if and only if $A \models T$.

Comment: I know that this is a valid implication and I used it in my proof of $T \vdash \alpha \Rightarrow T \models_t \alpha$. My problem is that I can't prove the *converse*, which would complete the proof.

Comment: @Godbless Ah, I see. It turns out the converse is false - see the edited proof.

Comment: @MarkSavings The converse does hold if the set of formulas $T$ is a *theory* (meaning, by the definition of theory, that all of its formulas are *sentences*). See my answer (to myself, lol :)) for the proof.

Comment: @Godbless Oh, because in that case, $(A, w) \models T$ if and only if $A \models T$.

Comment: Yep, that's the crucial part! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The author says $X\vdash_T\alpha$ stands for $X\cup T\vdash\alpha$. Of course you can generalize this to $\vDash$ and use $X\vDash_T\alpha$ to stand for $X\cup T\vDash\alpha$. If so, then

$$
\begin{array}{rcll}
T\vDash_T\alpha &\iff & T\cup T\vDash\alpha &\text{by convention}\\
&\iff & T\vDash\alpha &\text{by }T\cup T=T\\
&\iff & T\vdash\alpha &\text{by completeness and soundness}\\
&\iff & T\cup T\vdash\alpha &\text{by }T\cup T=T\\
&\iff & T\vdash_T\alpha &\text{by convention.}
\end{array}
$$

By the way, so far as I know, the shorthand $X\vdash_T\alpha$ is useful while $X\vDash_T\alpha$ is not.

Now return to your proof. It should be corrected as follows:

\begin{align*}
T \vdash \alpha &\Leftrightarrow T \models \alpha  &\text{(soundness and completeness of FOL)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{M} \models T \Rightarrow \mathcal{M} \models \alpha) &\text{(definition of $\vDash$)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow \color{red}{\forall \mathcal{A}\forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models T \Rightarrow (\mathcal{A}, w) \models \alpha) }&\text{(definition of $\vDash$)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall \mathcal{A}\forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models T\cup T \Rightarrow (\mathcal{A}, w) \models \alpha) &\text{($T\cup T=T$)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall \mathcal{A}(\mathcal{A} \models T\cup T \Rightarrow \mathcal{A} \models \alpha) &\text{(definition  of $\vDash$)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow T\cup T\models \alpha. &\text{(definition  of $\vDash$)}\\
&\Leftrightarrow T \models_T \alpha. &\text{(convention)}
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't think this proves what I wanted to prove, because $T \models_T \alpha$ has *not* been shown to be equivalent to $T \models_t \alpha$. By your definition, $T \models_T \alpha \Leftrightarrow T \cup T \models \alpha \Leftrightarrow T \models \alpha$, so $T \models_T \alpha$ is equivalent to $T \models \alpha$. But whether $T \models \alpha$ is equivalent to $T \models_t \alpha$ is precisely my question.

Comment: $T\vDash_t\alpha$ should be $T\vDash_T\alpha$, while $T\vDash_T\alpha$ stands for $T\cup T\vDash\alpha$ ("Stands for" means it's a convention and hence it's not necessary to show $T\vDash_T\alpha\iff T\cup T\vDash\alpha$ !).

Comment: I read the author's claim on p. 102 again, and it seems apparent to me that with $T \models \alpha$ he meant $T \models_t \alpha$ (as defined in my question). This has not been proven to be equivalent to $T \models_T \alpha$ in your post.

I re-read the reference on p. 102 *really carefully* again, and it is indeed ambiguous whether the author means $T \models \alpha$ or $T \models_t \alpha$ (both as defined in my question), though the former would seem redundant to me, as it would just be restating the completeness and soundness of *any* set of formulas.

Comment: @God bless In fact, the author doesn't use $\vDash_T$ at all. It's used by yourself, and you don't know why to use it and how to use it. I revised my answer which may be useful to you.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I am aware that the author doesn't use $\models_t$. I introduced it, because the satisfiability relation $\models$ means two different things when it stands between any set of formulas and a formula and when it stands between a *theory* and a formula. The definition of the latter is given on p. 82 and I used it in my proof (fifth line). The author takes it for granted that we will refer to that definition when a theory is in the antecedent, but I introduced new notation to avoid confusion.

Comment: The point is that (now using the author's notation) $T \models \alpha$ can mean two different things, depending on if we're thinking of $T$ as any set of formulas *or* a theory.

Comment: @God bless When we introduce a new notation, it's important that whether it will be used a lot. So far as I know, $\vDash_t$ is almost not useful. And also $\vDash$ in $\Sigma\vDash\alpha$ and $T\vDash\alpha$ are the same, and $\Sigma$ in $\Sigma\vDash\alpha$ and$T$ in $T\vDash\alpha$  are different.

Comment: I introduced it solely for the purpose of avoiding confusion regarding $T \models \alpha$, as it can have two different meanings, as I explained in the above comment. Now, I'm interested in the proof of $T \models_t \alpha \Rightarrow T \models \alpha$, as this is what the author seems to be claiming on p. 102.

Comment: @Godbless - in page 102 there is no $\vDash_t$... So what do you mean with "what the author seems to be claiming on p. 102"? The claim is Soundness and Completeness: $T \vdash \alpha \text { iff } T \vDash \alpha$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If the author has in mind the satisfiability relation as defined on p. 82, soundness and completeness do not immediately give this equivalence, as the satisfiability relation is defined differently when it stands between a *theory* and a formula (again, see p. 82) as opposed to when it stands between any set of formulas and a formula (for this, see p. 64).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to thank Mauro ALLEGRANZA for the crucial insight which proves the converse implication: $T$ is (by definition, because it's a theory) a set of *sentences*.

Let $\mathcal{A}_0$ be some structure and $w_0$ some variable assignment. Let
$$
\forall\mathcal{A}(\forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models T) \Rightarrow \forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models \alpha))
$$
be true. Then we have

\begin{align*}
(\mathcal{A}_0,w_0) \models T &\Rightarrow \forall w ((\mathcal{A}_0,w) \models T) &\text{(because $T$ is a set of sentences)} \\
&\Rightarrow \forall w ((\mathcal{A}_0,w) \models \alpha) &\text{(premise)} \\
&\Rightarrow (\mathcal{A}_0,w_0) \models \alpha. &\text{(valid implication)}
\end{align*}

This proves
$$
\forall\mathcal{A}(\forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models T) \Rightarrow \forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models \alpha)) \Rightarrow \forall \mathcal{A}\forall w((\mathcal{A}, w) \models T \Rightarrow (\mathcal{A}, w) \models \alpha),
$$

which, by the proof in the original post, proves $T \models_t \alpha \Rightarrow T \vdash \alpha$.